# A finite group with trivial intersection of arbitrary different Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. It is known that for every $P,S$ in $\operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$ (i.e the set of all Sylow subgroups of $G$) we have $P\cap S=1$.

> What can we say about $G$? Maybe there are another interesting properties of $G$?

Comment: There are lots examples, including some simple groups such as ${\rm PSL}(2,2^n)$. What sort of properties did you have in mind?

Comment: @DerekHolt, I try to solve the following problem (Isaacs FGT 5.E.1). Let $G$ be a finite group and suppose that every proper subgroup of $G$ has a normal $p$-complement, but $G$ itself doesn't. Show that $G$ has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup and $|G|$ has exactly one prime devisor other than $p$.  I reduce this problem to the case, where every pair of different Sylow $p$-groups has a trivial intersection.

Comment: You could try using Frobenius' Theorem (Thm 5.26).

Comment: @DerekHolt, thank you. I have already solved this problem using Frobenius' Theorem. But I also thouoght that this property(of Sylow subgroups) is rather restrictable so there should be another interesting properties of such groups.

Comment: The normalizers of such Sylow $p$-subgroups are *strongly* $p$-*embedded*. Search for this term and the name "Helmut Bender".

Comment: @j.p., thank you